# C/C++ style -- modifying function arguments

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, pass-by-value

Everyone knows that C/C++ function arguments are pass-by-value. So why do some people insist that correct style is to make a local copy of a function argument before modifying it?  For example, they would write:

```
void baz(unsigned int *ptr)
{
  unsigned int *lPtr = ptr;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
      foo(*lPtr++);
  }
}
```

instead of:

```
void baz(unsigned int *ptr)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
      foo(*ptr++);
  }
}
```

It seems like the second way is easier to read since it is one less variable.

Comment: I never understood why people do this either. Maybe those who come from C++ are accustomed to the risk of passing and modifying a reference accidentally... euh, not so good.

Comment: Maybe so that the original values of function arguments can easily be seen in any core dump files?  I don't really know.

Comment: Who are these people? I agree with you.

Comment: Same here... Then I guess it's not really everyone...

Comment: I once saw notes for a 'learning C' course which taught a highly formulaic approach which included this sort of thing. Feels like a waste of space to me.

Comment: "Everyone knows that C/C++ function arguments are pass-by-value" really?  we do?  and why do you clump c and c++ here?

Comment: 1. Arguments are NOT pass-by-value. There are references. 2. I never understood why some people insist on putting {} around single line of code, 3. Your 2nd example doesn't even need pointer arithmetics `void baz(unsigned int *ptr){for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) foo(ptr[i]);}` 4. There's probably no "correct" style.

Comment: For your contrived example it may make no sense, but in real code maybe they needed the original value and also one that they could modify.  It all depends on the context in the actual code.

Comment: thang -- yes everyone knows that. that is one of the first concepts you will learn in any C programming class. SigTerm - Yes there are references, but you can see from the function declaration that it is not a reference. Retired Ninja - This is real code with function names changed to protect their identity (i.e. intellectual property).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only justification is for much larger functions, someone may add new functionality to the bottom of a function not realizing that the parameter was modified or made invalid earlier up.

Imagine:

```
int bighorriblefunction(const char * astr)
{
  // hundreds of lines of horribleness
  while ( * astr ) { /* something */  ++ astr ; }

  // more pages of code

  /** author two adds later */
  if ( ! strcmp(astr, "magicvalue") ) { /** do this really important thing **/  return 1 ; }
  return 0 ;
}
```

Its going to take author two a while to realize that the new code is never going to run.

Answer (score 2):

They do it because the original value is useful when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the author of the code wrote the declaration of the variable in the first version of `baz()`, and then he refactored the code, which moved the code in the for loop into the function `foo()`, and the author mistakenly didn't remove the variable. The variable is pure waste. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

That's a poor man's version of separation of interface from implementation.

Supposed you wrote this code a year ago:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void bar( const char *where )
    {
        // The dreaded copy
        const char *destination = where;

        // The actual implementation that in the real world may take 500 
        // lines of code with 20 references to the variable destination
    }
};
```

And now, a year later, you want to make the parameter **where** optional, defaulted to a member variable of the class. Alas, you don't remember what exactly those 500 lines of code do! Fortunately, you are saved by the virtue of the parameter being copied before use:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void bar( const char *where = NULL)
    {
        // Hooray! I only have to change 1 line here!
        const char *destination = where? where : m_MyHomeDir.c_str();

        // The actual implementation that in the real world may take 500 
        // lines of code with 20 references to the variable destination
    }

private:
    std::string m_MyHomeDir;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in C++, just use:

```
std::for_each(ptr, ptr+10, foo);
```

I know, that doesn't answer the question directly, but does point toward the fact that it should usually be irrelevant. If it is relevant you probably need to rewrite the code in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear who these "some people" are (I've never heard of this demand), but the only legitimate reason I can think of for it is that it slightly aids in debugging: if the debugger stops the function in the middle, you can see the argument values it was originally called with. However in most cases you can achieve the same thing by just moving up one call frame and looking at the values of the expressions that were passed to the function.