# Why convert parameters to local variables in a function?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm a beginner and I remember reading somewhere, but unfortunately do not remember where, that it is good practice to first convert parameters of a function to local variables, before working with them. Could someone explain why?

```
void MyFunction(type param)
{
  type myVar = param;

  //do stuff with myVar instead of param
}
```

I'm guessing if `param` passed into `MyFunction` was a pointer then it might be possible the data that it's pointing to could change while `MyFunction` is being executed, but are there other reasons?

Comment: If this is C++, that's already a copy (assuming `type` isn't a type alias for a reference, but then it'd have the same problem as C#). If this is C# and that's a reference type, `myVar` is going to be another reference to the same thing.

Comment: no that's not a good practice (at least in C#). it doesn't make any sense and it's too redundant. Forget all that and use parameters directly

Comment: First you need to clarify whether you're talking about C# or C++. The answers may vary greatly.

Comment: You might be thinking of javascript.. where it is good practice to declare `var self = this;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to do the copy in any modern language that passes by value.

It would have been useful in older languages, like Algol, that pass parameters by name. See this [example](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/383/PassByName.html).

Comment: Note that VBA passes by reference too.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad;; when `type myVar = param;`, type's copy constructor called. It's unnecessary unless you use both `myVar` and `param` for different purposes.

edit: If `type`'s copy cost is almost free, It can be used for convenience and readability.

Answer (score 0):

There are some answers to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254826/c-c-style-modifying-function-arguments/20255123#20255123). The answers why one would copy a value that has already been copied point mostly to maintainability considerations.